# identifying different variables in a given function

Tags: c++

Given a mathematical expression say `x1x2` or `x1^2+x2^2`

I need to write a C++ program which takes the expression from the end user and inside of it and replace `x1`, `x2` with some array values like `x1` with `a[1]` etc.

How to do this please help me.

This is the first time im using cpp.

```
int main()
{     
    float i;
    char* exp[20]; 
    derivtype g(derivtype x);
    cin>>i;
    cin>>exp;

    for(i=1:i<=i:i++)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement a parser for math expressions. That is a hard task for a C++ beginner.

Comment: It's not your C++ knowledge that's letting you down here, you need to learn parsing theory.

Comment: @Andrey and Tony: Am I missing something, or would a simple string replacement be enough? The question does not mention anything about evaluating the expression.

Comment: @LucTouraille: The task is not clear enough... Even if evaluating the expression is not required, some parsing would be needed, e.g., to distinguish `x1` and `x11` variables.

Comment: If there were only two variables and they were always called x1 and x11, you replace x11 first, and there was no requirement to evaluate, then the question would be hardly worth asking...

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is the domain of compiler.

What you need is tool such as lex/yacc tool to recognize the syntax of those mathematical expressions. From there you can customize.

You can start with some some sample codes or tutorial, such as [Lex & Yacc Tutorial](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/)